# Deleting Older Posts

Tags: discussion, answers

I tried deleting some of the older answers which I had posted but could not delete more than five. These were the ones which were wrong or out of context or had something wrong with them. Why is this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what happened:

The system detects 'vandalism', aka RAGEQUIT's. It thought you were rage quitting, so the system stopped you from deleting anything else. If you're serious about cleaning up, you have three options:

- Flag those posts for deletion, with a comment explaining why - then the mods can help.
- Find me (or another mod) in chat and then we can help you.
- Or, wait a week or two and do it again.